# How to use the result of an inner observable while using ngrx selector?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, ngrx

In My app, at some point I have the following code :

```
  this.missionHelperService.checkMissionPoint(position).subscribe(result => {

  });
```

Now, checkMissionPoint is supposed to do the following =>

1. -Get a value from a store
2. -Execute an API call
3. -Return the API result

I am trying to make it return the result of the observable, but I can't manage to find the correct syntax

```
  checkMissionPoint(position: Cartographic): Observable<CheckMissionResponse> {
    const params = {
      latitude: CesiumMath.rad2Deg(position.latitude),
      longitude: CesiumMath.rad2Deg(position.longitude),
      altitude: position.height,
    };

    return this.store$.pipe(select(TransactionsStoreSelectors.selectedTransactionId), take(1)).pipe(
      map((tId) => {
        return this.httpClient.post<any>(`${environment.API_URL}/trajectories/${tId}/checkpoints`, params);
      })
    )
  }
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: So you need to do two api calls?

Comment: no I need a single api call,and subscribe to the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try switchMap, since you are returning a new observable:

```
checkMissionPoint(position: Cartographic): Observable<CheckMissionResponse> {
  const params = {
    latitude: CesiumMath.rad2Deg(position.latitude),
    longitude: CesiumMath.rad2Deg(position.longitude),
    altitude: position.height,
  };

  return this.store$.pipe(
    select(TransactionsStoreSelectors.selectedTransactionId), 
    take(1),
    switchMap((tId) => {
      return this.httpClient.post<any>(`${environment.API_URL}/trajectories/${tId}/checkpoints`, params);
    })
  );
}
```